# Russian listening for A1 level

Tags: resource-request, listening, russian

I have a proficiency level of A1 in Russian and I'm looking forward to improve it. One way I imagine could be beneficial, would be listening everyday to native speakers in the form of podcasts, for example. Is there a repository of resources someone at my level can download and listen to and can "reasonably" understand (as in: I don't expect to understand 100% of the content and even if it's a bit out of my level that would be ok)?

Comment: It would be helpful to have some background infos, like where you are?

Comment: what do you mean with "where you are"?

Comment: I mean your location. There are many places on the planet with substantial Russian-speaking population. Germany is one example. If, for instance, you were in Karlsruhe, you could just go to Werderplatz and listen and talk to native Russian speakers without any podcasts.

Comment: @badbishop you can't really expect a beginner to go to a market and start chatting with natives. Typical A1 learners are still struggling with simple conversations in a controlled environment of a class led by professional teacher.

Comment: @MiloBem: If a "beginner" is at A1 level already, I see no problem. I've learned German at Goethe Institut starting at about A1, and the first rule was: no other language in the class other than German. Yes, it's painful in the beginning, but no pain - no gain. On the other hand, if you learn textbook Russian, you will speak textbook Russian (which will immediately identify you as a foreigner). The way most Russians speak English proves my point (just in reverse).